# Is there such thing as a chimichilada?

Tags: deep-frying

So a burrito is made with a flour tortilla; it is wet if you put sauce on it.

An enchilada is basically just a wet burrito, but made with a corn tortilla.

A chimichanga is a deep fried burrito.

What is it called if you deep fry an enchilada instead of or before putting sauce on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between burritos, chimichanga, and enchiladas?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/77310/difference-between-burritos-chimichanga-and-enchiladas) -- although not sure if the corn/flour tortillas difference is enough to change a chimichanga (which can be served with sauce)

Answer (score 4):

There's an additional complication to your question. Chimichangas are closed-ended while enchiladas are open-ended, so calling an enchilada a wet burrito isn't quite right. In fact, burritos often come drenched in sauce. For reference, the [Chuy's Fajita beef burrito with ranchero sauce](https://www.chuys.com/menu):

[image: Chuy's Fajita Beef Burrito with ranchero sauce. Burrito on a plate covered with red sauce and melted cheese, Mexican rice, and salad.]

Other differences include size, which changes how many you're served. You're generally going to eat one burrito or chimichanga while you'll get 2-4 enchiladas (or more, depending on size).

I think the more similar fried (or baked), open-ended corn tortilla food you're looking for is a "[taquito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taquito)" or "flauta" (the latter is often with a flour tortilla, too).

> A taquito (Spanish pronunciation: [taˈkito], literally Spanish for "small taco"), tacos dorados, rolled taco, or flauta (Spanish pronunciation: [ˈflauta], literally Spanish for "flute") is a Mexican food dish that typically consists of a small rolled-up tortilla that contains filling, including beef, cheese or chicken. The filled tortilla is then crisp-fried or deep-fried. The dish is often topped with condiments such as sour cream and guacamole. Corn tortillas are generally used to make taquitos; the dish is more commonly known as flautas when they are larger than their taquito counterparts, and can be made with either flour or corn tortillas although using corn is more traditional.

Because it's crispy-fried, they're generally not topped with a liquid sauce, which helps preserve the crisp shell, particularly as they are generally eaten as finger food.

Some potato taquitos from [Hilah Cooking](https://hilahcooking.com/potato-taquitos-tacos-dorados-de-papa/):

[image: Potato taquitos on a plate with a green sauce and some garnish.]

---

Full disclosure: I enjoy dining at Chuy's but am unaffiliated with them. I know Hilah but found this image/recipe serendipitously in a Google search.